# forwarding calls to non-twilio number

Tags: forward

i'm new at this. Trying this code, [howtos/phonemenu/phonemenu.php](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/phonemenu) but calls are able to be forwarded to numbers purchased from twilio but won't forward to other non-twilio numbers, even though this is a verified number. Any help?

Comment: I do that all the time. Can you post some code? Ideally, you should upgrade your account, that way you won't have to verify the "to" numbers

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I do have an upgraded account. I used to be able to forward calls to non-twilio numbers but that has not been working of late.

Comment: Solved. I had inadvertently disabled international calling to North America.